# I am not able to connect to the database using django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am able to connect to the database using MySQLdb , but not able to connect using the django 
please any body help me out

All parameters are correct , like host,password and username.

when ever i tried import something  python interpreter regarding django i am getting the following error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

of course i have django installed.

please help me out , i am new to django....

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you run `python manage.py shell` so that all django-specific environment variables are loaded.

If you just run `python`, then you'll get errors like the one you posted since the django environment is not correctly setup.

Answer (score 0):

Import the value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

This can be either done by:

1. Adding the project directory to $PYTHONPATH.
2. Change DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to projectfoldername.settings.

Comment: i inserted the project directory path  to the python path
through sys.path.insert(0,os.getcwd())

but even i am not able to connect the database, please please tell me the way . I was stuck at that point it is working fine in other system , but it is not in my machine that i recently installed the
os (linux)

Answer (score 0):

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE - is the environment variable, set it to your projects settings.py file.

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "yourprojectname.settings"
```

More info at : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

Comment: @usernaveen: Try this:

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings

django-admin.py runserver`